# How to use Microsoft Word editor in Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I use the Word editor in a WPF application? 
I have found [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit) but it does not solve the whole purpose as it lacks many features that are required by my application.
So I want to know that is it possible to use Word  editor in a native way in a Wpf app? Will all APIs be available in that solution?
Any help would be great.

Comment: Microsoft charges money for their Microsoft Word. Why would they make it's core available to the public? You have to do the implementing yourself I am afraid.

Comment: As from what I understand, you are looking for Word editor UI? Not a Word document API?

Comment: The built-in `RichTextBox` has a lot of features. Of course, you would need to code in your own UI, but that isn't terribly difficult.